# Extract frames from a video and converts the binary data of each pixel into bytes and writes the decoded information as text

Tags: javascript, react-native, matlab, image-processing, expo

So I’m doing a react natives apps that could decode the video of coloured barcodes that generated from Matlab. I’m thinking about extract each frames from the video using ffmpegkit but not sure how and not sure about how to get each pixel colours to be convert back to binaries and convert back to text. What’s the best option to go?

I have tried other libraries but nothing seems able to do the job